# Possible to show an on-page progress while downloading a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, download, ashx

On a website, I'm successfully using an ASHX handler to download files from the server to visitors of my website.

A customer suggested to not rely on the browser UI to visualize the download progress but instead provide some progress *on the page* to provide a more visual cue.

I.e. first, the user sees a download page with a link/button:

[image]

Then, when clicking the <kbd>**Download your file now!**</kbd> button something like this should appear:

[image]

Unfortunately, even after searching Google and SO for hours, I found zero similar topics. All occurrences deal with *upload*, not download. Either I'm using the wrong keywords or there are really no solutions.

**Therefore my question:**

(How) would it be possible to provide such a download progress?

Comment: I think, this link will be helpful for you : http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-download-a-file-in-c-progressbar-and-download-speed/

Comment: Maybe this is also intresting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461010/asynctask-with-a-updatepanel/ 
It actually doesnt care if its a up- or download, because all you need to know is how to update the frontend while you have the download in the background. Its the same as with an upload just the other way, but you need to know how to display it. Maybe the answer in my question will help you.

Comment: @AnuragJain I dont think this link is helpfull, because he is asking for asp.net stuff, and not for windowsform. This is something completly different as far as you have a client-server-relation in asp.net

Comment: @DatRid : This link use as reference not as answer that's why I put this link as comment.

Comment: Thanks, guys. The Winform articles are what I found, too. And why I then decided to ask here :-)

Comment: I believe the only way of being able to pull this off is having the file download via a service that you coded yourself on a low level where you can poll for the amount of bytes sent and then use SignalR or something to show the progress on your webpage...

Comment: Usually when you are downloading something from the web your browser shows you a progress bar, hence you won't probably find a lot of information about the subject because downloading is not handled by the website rather by the browser/client.

Comment: @IvanL , could you perhaps point to some examples in that direction? I'm looking to achieve same thing as in the question.

Comment: @tatigo Sorry I'm not aware of any examples. I just suggested a code of action I'd take to try and resolve the issue.